# Wordpress Advanced search, with tree and filters and live search

Tags: wordpress, search, filter, tree

I am looking to put an advanced search feature into my Wordpress website in witch i am going to sell several thousand different used car parts. So i need a way to filter the results AND search in a certain subcategory ( like i wanna filter for make and year and then search for the front left part)

I want something like this http://www.kiparissis.gr/ ( the yellow box in the middle)

It has a search free option  and a filter and a tree from product categories , and it shows live how many results there are!

Is there a way to get something like this with an ad-don ? Since i am a total rookie and i like to use as less code as possible.

Thanks all!

Comment: At First i thought about using a menu-type tree to make it easy for the customer to find the sub-category he wants, but i cant either filter out other models , nor to search live(show how many results)

Answer (score 0):

Would a custom google search bar be of use? Some site use this for their searching, it would mean a lot less code for you.
If you're selling car parts though you'd be using a plugin in WordPress to manage that such as woocomerce, this would come with search functionality as you described.

Comment: I already have woocomerce. But i want to make it easy for the customer to find the part he want to. 

Well if woocomercehas that functionality i haven't found it yet :-/ ...

The reason i want filters is for the customer to be able to find his model-car , And the reason i need the tree is for the customer to be able to locate his part ( for example, mechanical -> suspencion -> zamfor -> zamfor plates etc) There are hundreds of different categories and  hundreds of models. Thats why i need an advanced search for the customer, but i just cant get my head around it !

Comment: And i have to always assume that the custom knows very little about cars !

Comment: These are the official search extensions available if you're willing to spend a bit of money. https://woocommerce.com/product-category/woocommerce-extensions/product-extensions/search-navigation/

Comment: Thnx A lot! I am willing to spend some money , but none of these comes not even close to what i want :-(